awk search and replace by a string containing "\n" will add a new line instead of writing "\n"
I use Awk to search a keyword <replaceme> and replace it by a string. This string contains the chars "\n", but Awk interprets it as a new line. I really want to keep both characters, \ and n.
I've a string containing a real new line and I need to replace it by the chars "\n".
It works:
mytext=$'hello\nhow are you'
mytext2=${mytext//$'\n'/\\n}

echo "$mytext"
hello
how are you

echo "$mytext2"
hello\nhow are you

Then I have a keyword <replaceme> in a text and I would like to replace it by the content of $mytext2
echo 'this is the text: <replaceme>' |
awk -v srch="<replaceme>" -v repl="$mytext2" '{
    gsub(srch,repl,$0); print $0 }'

I get this result.
this is the text: hello
how are you

But I would like:
this is the text: hello\nhow are you

How to proceed, please?
Note: in fact, the text "this is the text: " is in a file and I use cat myfile.txt | awk...

Change repl to repl="${mytext2//\\/\\\\}". You need to make sure the backslash before n is doubled so that \n could not be parsed as a newline.

You may use this awk solution:
mytext=$'hello\nhow are you'
echo 'this is the text: <replaceme>' |
awk -v srch="<replaceme>" -v repl="${mytext//$'\n'/\\\\n}" '{gsub(srch,repl)} 1'

this is the text: hello\nhow are you

BASH replacement ${mytext//$'\n'/\\\\n} will replace each instance of \n with \\n before passing that string as awk argument repl.

Pure awk solution (without bash):
echo 'this is the text: <replaceme>' |
awk -v srch="<replaceme>" '
BEGIN {
   repl = ARGV[1]
   gsub(/\n/, "\\n", repl)
   delete ARGV[1]
}
{
   gsub(srch, repl)
} 1' "$mytext"

this is the text: hello\nhow are you


You're specifically ASKING awk to convert \n to a literal newline by using -v to set the awk variables as interpreting escape sequences is what -v is designed to do. If that's not the behavior you want then just don't do that - use ENVIRON[] or ARGV[] to populate the awk variables instead so the shell variable or string contents are passed to awk as-is:
$ mytext=$'hello\nhow are you'
$ mytext2=${mytext//$'\n'/\\n}
$ echo 'this is the text: <replaceme>' |
old="<replaceme>" mytext2="$mytext2" awk '
    BEGIN { srch=ENVIRON["old"]; repl=ENVIRON["mytext2"] }
    { gsub(srch,repl,$0); print $0 }
'
this is the text: hello\nhow are you


$ mytext=$'hello\nhow are you'
$ mytext2=${mytext//$'\n'/\\n}
$ echo 'this is the text: <replaceme>' |
awk '
    BEGIN { srch=ARGV[1]; repl=ARGV[2]; ARGV[1]=ARGV[2]="" }
    { gsub(srch,repl,$0); print $0 }
' "<replaceme>" "$mytext2"
this is the text: hello\nhow are you

See How do I use shell variables in an awk script? for more information.
Note that since you're using gsub() to do the search and replace you still have to worry about regexp metachars like . or * in the srch string and a backreference metachar, &, in the repl string.
If you want to do literal string search and replace then you either need to escape any possible metachars, e.g. (untested):
old="<replaceme>" mytext2="$mytext2" awk '
    BEGIN {
        srch = ENVIRON["old"]
        repl = ENVIRON["mytext2"]
        gsub(/[^^\\]/, "[&]", srch)
        gsub(  /\\/  ,  "&&", srch)
        gsub(  /\^/  , "\\&", srch)
        gsub(   /&/  , "\\&", repl)
    }
    { gsub(srch,repl,$0); print $0 }
'

(see Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed for the sed equivalent and explanation of what those gsub()s are doing) or use string operators (index() and substr()) instead of regexp+backreference (gsub()).
By the way, it's not obvious why you're starting with a string hello\nhow are you that contains the 2 characters \n, then using bash's $'...' to convert that to a newline, then using ${mytext//$'\n'/\\n} to convert it back to \n, then calling awk with -v to convert it back to a newline, then asking how to print it as the original 2 characters \n. You're doing:

'hello\nhow are you'         -> \n
mytext=$'hello\nhow are you' -> <newline>
mytext2=${mytext//$'\n'/\\n} -> \n
awk -v repl="$mytext2"       -> <newline>
awk '{... print ...}'        -> \n (wanted)

Seems like you may be doing a few too many conversions there! You could have avoided the first 2 or 3 conversions in your question by just starting with mytext2='hello\nhow are you' or even awk -v repl='hello\nhow are you'

Thank you all of you for your responses! It works.
Yes my example isn't obvious, I wanted to share a quick example which describe the problem. I also didn't want to copy/paste some code which is related to the company where I work, so I created this dummy example.
Unfortunately I don't have any knowledge with Awk, I used -v because I found an example on internet to use variable with -v.
So I could solve my issue with
repl="${mytext//$'\n'/\\\\n}"

Yes I do lots of conversion. Can we avoid and have a nicer nicer solution?
In fact, my real use case is:

I've a script which create several certificates.
The contents of the certificates must be included inside certificates.json (with a specific JSON structure).
I created certificates.json.tpl (template) which contains some parameters <certificates_1>, <certificates_2>, <certificates_3>, etc. where the content of the file must be copied/pasted.
What I did:

To read certificates_1.pem with 'cat' and put it in a variable $certificates_1. Same for _2, _3 etc.
With Awk, replace <certificates_1> by $certificates_1 in certificates.json.tpl (template) to generate certificates.json. Same for _2 and _3 etc.
One certificate is in PEM format and contains new lines. The tools which process certificate.json requires literal \n instead.



Can awk take the content of a file as argument?
My current solution which is working but not elegant
certificates.json.tpl:
{ 
  "pkcs12": [ 
    { 
      "name": "certificats_1-key", 
      "certificate-name": "certificats_1-cert", 
      "pkcs12": "<certificats_1>", 
      "password": "<password>" 
    }, 
    { 
      "name": "certificats_2-key", 
      "certificate-name": "certificats_2-cert", 
      "pkcs12": "<certificats_2>", 
      "password": "<password>" 
    }, 
    {
      "name": "certificats_3-key", 
      "certificate-name": "certificats_3-cert", 
      "pkcs12": "<certificats_3>", 
      "password": "<password>" 
    } 
  ], 
  "ca-certs": [ 
    { 
      "name": "certificats_trusted", 
      "pem": "<certificats_trusted>" 
    } 
  ] 
}

password="thisisasecret"
certificates_1=$(cat certificates_1.p12.base64)
certificates_2=$(cat certificates_2.p12.base64)
certificates_3=$(cat certificates_3.p12.base64)
certificates_trusted=$(cat certificates_trusted.pem)


cat certificates.json.tpl |
awk -v srch="<password>" -v repl="$password" '
    { gsub(srch,repl,$0); print $0 }' |
awk -v srch="<certificates_1>" -v repl="$certificates_1" '
    { gsub(srch,repl,$0); print $0 }' |
awk -v srch="<certificates_2>" -v repl="$certificates_2" '
    { gsub(srch,repl,$0); print $0 }' |
awk -v srch="<certificates_3>" -v repl="$certificates_3" '
    { gsub(srch,repl,$0); print $0 }' |
awk -v srch="<certificates_trusted>" -v repl="${certificates_trusted//$'\n'/\\\\n}" '
    { gsub(srch,repl,$0); print $0 }' > certificates.json

